# semantic ui submit button in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I have a problem

This is my modal window code:

```
    <div class="ui modal"> <i class="close icon"></i>
        <div class="header">Modal Title</div>
        <div class="content">
           <form class="ui form" method="post" action="example.com">
               <div class="image">An image can appear on left or an icon</div>
               <div class="description">A description can appear on the right</div>
               <div class="ui input" name="a">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
               </div>
               <div class="actions">
                  <div class="ui button">Cancel</div>
                  <div class="ui button">OK</div>
                  <input type="submit" value="submit" class="ui button">
               </div>
            </form>
    </div>
```

```
<script>  

$('.ui.modal')
  .modal('show')
;

</script>
```

The problem is the submit button does not work. Please help me what i do?

Comment: It's kinda difficult to determine from the code.  It could be a back end thing.  
That said, action="example.com" will never work if that's actually in your markup.

Comment: your code works .. the way you coded it, it will find whatever domain you post, as long as you put in a https:// and www. before it  https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/41me4cgu/  is that the intended action or no?

Comment: Is your console showing any errors?

Comment: @SunSparc i just posted.. the code works!

Comment: Yep, saw that. It is nice when code works in a standalone environment. However, there can often be conflicts when introduced into an environment with other code. Hence my question about console errors.

Comment: This is the modal window in framework Semantic-UI. 
The console does not show any errors.

Comment: I think that it's related to the control of the buttons done by the modal. You can read it on the documentation `Close actions are applied by default to all button actions, in addition an onApprove or onDeny callback will fire if the elements match either selector.`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this (still) seems to be a problem with the way Modals work in Semantic/Fomantic UI: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2554

One way around is to set detachable:false which keeps the controls within the DOM and the buttons working as expected (as explained in the documentation ([Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/usage), [Fomantic UI](https://fomantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#via-existing-dom-node)).

Other possible workarounds (none too satisfactory for complex pages) are outlined in the link above, but if your case is simple enough adding a form='formName' to the submit input element might be all that is required, as demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/efp8z6Ln/158/

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" form="theform" class="ui button">
```